# Calling web service with XML post method and getting response in XML format which is very slow response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, xml-parsing

Here I am getting proper result but my problem is very slow response getting from the server.
Please suggest any other fastest method to call web service. Help appreciated.

```
 String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><availabilityRequest cancelpolicy = \"Y\">with more condition</availabilityRequest>


String responseStr = postXMLData("http://service-url", xml);
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(responseStr);

public String postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
    {
        string responseStr = "";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        return responseStr;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is good enough for calling web service (apart of not disposing streams, and mismatch in encoding ASCII and utf-8). Verify where the lag is - using fiddler for instance you can determine if the service that you are calling is taking long to respond. If that is the case maybe you are asking for to much data or the service needs to be optimized.